# What is JSONEncoder c_make_encoder?

Tags: python, json

I LOVE the python module json, and I love json.dumps(); however, I hate the fact that you need to pass additional arguments to it if you want to extend its behaviour.

I am strong believer that classes should take care of themselves, so I created the class `Serialisable` that goes like this:

```
class Serialisable(dict[str, Any]):
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.items())
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(dict(self.items()))
    def __getitem__(self, __key: str) -> Any: 
        return getattr(self, __key)
    def __setitem__(self, __key: str, __value: Any) -> None:
        vars(self)[__key] = __value
    def __delitem__(self, __key: str) -> None:
        variable = getattr(self, __key)
        del variable
    def __contains__(self, __key: str) -> bool:
        return __key in vars(self)
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[str]:
        return self.keys().__iter__()
    def keys(self) -> list[str]:
        return [keys for keys, _ in self.items()]
    def values(self) -> list[Any]:
        return [values for _, values in self.items()]
    def items(self) -> list[tuple[str, Any]]:
        result: list[tuple[str, Any]] = []
        for name, value in vars(self).items():
            variable = getattr(self, name)
            if isinstance(variable, Serialisable): pass
            elif 'builtin' not in variable.__class__.__module__: continue
            result.append((name, value))
        return result
```

Basically, if you have a sub class of `Serialisable`, all of the instance variables (that are serialisable) will appear as part of a dictionary:

```
@dataclass
class subSerial(Serialisable):
    boolean: bool = True
    real: float = -1.0

@dataclass
class NonSerial:
    string: str = 'Miguel'

class mainSerial(Serialisable):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.string: str = 'Calgary'
        self.integer: int = 53
        self.subClass: subSerial = subSerial()
        self.name: dict[str, str] = {'King': 'Charles'}
        self.discard: NonSerial = NonSerial()

print(f"{serial}")
```

> {'string': 'Calgary', 'integer': 53, 'subClass': subSerial(boolean=True, real=-1.0), 'name': {'King': 'Charles'}}

If I run this code `print(f"JSON indent = {json.dumps(serial, sort_keys=True, indent=4)}")`

I get this pretty result:

```
JSON indent = {
    "integer": 28,
    "name": {
        "King": "Charles"
    },
    "string": "Calgary",
    "subClass": {
        "boolean": true,
        "real": -1.0
    }
}
```

If I remove the `indent=4`, I get this:

```
JSON NON indent = {}
```

Long story short, it all boils down to how Python has implemented `json.dumps()` and this piece of code on `encoder.py`

```
        if (_one_shot and c_make_encoder is not None
                and self.indent is None):
            _iterencode = c_make_encoder(
                markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent,
                self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
                self.skipkeys, self.allow_nan)
        else:
            _iterencode = _make_iterencode(
                markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
                self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
                self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
        return _iterencode(o, 0)
```

`c_make_encoder` **seems** to be an external library function (written in C?) that apparently doesn't understand how custom dictionaries work!

So, here is(are) my question(s):

1. Do you know what I am missing on my `Serialisable` class to make it act a like a full dictionary and `json.dumps()`serialises it properly? **alternatively**
2. Do you know where can I find the code of c_make_encoder?

(I have found this very useless code on `_json.pyi`)

```
@final
class make_encoder:
    @property
    def sort_keys(self) -> bool: ...
    @property
    def skipkeys(self) -> bool: ...
    @property
    def key_separator(self) -> str: ...
[...]
```

Comment: That code is part of Python itself. You can study the code to answer your first question, if that's possible at all. Try to check the bug tracker for Python (it's on github) for similar issues and possibly file your own.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found a somewhat elegant solution for dump and dumps WITHOUT refactoring my code (by doing something like `json.dumps(object.to_dictionary())` using decorators!

```
import json

from typing import Callable, Any

def classdumps(function: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Any]:
    def dictionary(item: Any) -> Any:
        if isinstance(item, int): return int(item)
        elif isinstance(item, float): return float(item)
        elif isinstance(item, str): return str(item)
        elif isinstance(item, bool): return bool(item)
        elif isinstance(item, list): return [dictionary(item) for item in item]
        elif isinstance(item, dict): return {dictionary(key): dictionary(value) for key, value in item.items()}
        elif isinstance(item, object): return {name: dictionary(value) for name, value in vars(item).items()}
        raise ValueError(f"{item.__name__} has a type {type(item).__name__} which is not serialisable!")
    def wrapper(item: Any, *args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        result = dictionary(item)
        return function(result, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

original_dumps = json.dumps
@classdumps
def dumps(*args, **kwargs) -> str:
    return original_dumps(*args, **kwargs)
json.dumps = dumps

original_dump = json.dump
@classdumps
def dump(*args, **kwargs) -> None:
    return original_dump(*args, **kwargs)
json.dump = dump
```

now, if I just `import decoratorDumps`, I redefine `json.dump` and `json.dumps` and I can use it seamlessly everywhere!